# Passing multiple parameters in an object's property function to avoid calling multiple times

Tags: javascript

```
blah = [[1,"a"], [2,"b"], [3,"c"]]
var example = {x: blah };
example.addItem = function(number,letter){
     this.x.push([number,letter])
};

example.addItem(4, "d");
example.addItem(5, "e");
```

I was wondering how I might add multiple values using one call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function can accept an arbitrary sequence of values - either with an array (explicitly, a single argument) or with the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object (implicitly, with a variadic number of arguments).

Explicitly - accept an array of items:

```
function add(items) {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
     x.push(items[i]);
  }
}

add([[4, "d"], [5, "e"]])
```

Implicitly #1 - accept any number of parameters that are supplied as single values:

```
function add(/* item1, item2, .. */) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
     x.push(arguments[i]);
  }
}

add([4, "d"], [5, "e"])
```

Implicitly #2 - accept any number of parameters that are supplied as pairs:

```
function add(/* k1, v1, k2, v2, .. */) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i += 2)
     x.push([arguments[i], arguments[i+1])
  }
}

add(4, "d", 5, "e")
```

---

`Array.splice` or `concat` might be useful; such are not shown for simplicity and consistency.

Comment: concat would be my first choice, why use a for loop?

Comment: @goldylucks Alternative methods of iterating and/or manipulating arrays are secondary to the question of avoiding calling a function (in this case it was taken to be the `addItem` function) multiple times. Using `concat` also adds a disparity with the variadic-as-pairs form shown as the source is not a sequence of array-tuples.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change `addItem` you can do this:

```
[[4, "d"], [5, "e"]].forEach((params) => example.addItem.apply(example, params))
```